# Create a button for additional thing and for having a sequence in Panel

Tags: python

I want to add a sequence to my addon, for that I created 2 buttons `Next` and `Back` but I could not figure out how those buttons work.

I looking for is that when I click on the `Next` button then the second code should pop up. The second code can be seen in the second screenshot and I want that exact same as it is. After that when I add any object by those operators, those operators should be removed from the `panel` only properties and the `Subdivide` button should be left.

```
import bpy
    
class ADDON_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Add Objects"
    bl_idname = "pl.add_mesh"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Add Objects"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout        
        
        #The buttons in the beginning        
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text='Welcome to our addon.')
        col.label(text='Press Next to continue')
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator('op.back_thing', text='Back')
        row.operator('op.next_thing')
        
        #The buttons in the mid   
#        layout.label(text='Select object you want to add')
#        col = layout.column(align=True)
#        col.operator('op.add_cube')
#        col.operator('op.add_uv_sphere')
#        col.operator('op.add_monkey')

        #The buttons in the mid-process
#        if bpy.context.active_object:
#            layout.prop(bpy.context.object, 'location')
#            layout.prop(bpy.context.object, 'rotation_euler', text='Rotation')
#            layout.prop(bpy.context.object, 'scale')
#        
#        row = layout.row(align=True)
#        row.operator('op.back_thing')
#        row.operator('op.next_thing')        
        
        
class NEXT_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Next"
    bl_idname = "op.next_thing"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BACK_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Back"
    bl_idname = "op.back_thing"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
class ADD_CUBE_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Cube"
    bl_idname = "op.add_cube"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ADD_UV_SPHERE_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add UV Sphere"
    bl_idname = "op.add_uv_sphere"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ADD_MONKEY_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Suzanne"
    bl_idname = "op.add_monkey"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}

    
classes = (ADDON_PANEL, NEXT_OP, BACK_OP, ADD_CUBE_OPERATOR,ADD_UV_SPHERE_OPERATOR,ADD_MONKEY_OPERATOR)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You would add that into the poll method of your menu. Basically a method that checks for certain conditions of your current context to see if it should be shown or not. See the [Rigify addon](https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/blob/master/rigify/ui.py#L51) for an example of this kind of thing

Comment: I want them in the same context as they are now, I want the `next` button to work properly as it should.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense with the UI template your using and doesn't really make sense with how Blender works. Just do a props_dialog or a popup and put all of the properties in one dialog. If it gets too for that then maybe movie into the properties panel and do it there. Blender is all about minimizing clicks. No one in the middle of a workflow wants to have to sit and click "Next" 4x for no reason.

Comment: Also that's not how `col.operator()` works. Clicking that button will just call the operator immediately. You might need to create custom scene properties and then refer to those in a bigger operator.

Comment: This one seems okay, I will give it a try.
Thanks